# How a command from main window be handled in a usercontrol view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

In my application I have several user controls in a window. These user controls need to communicate to each other. My approach is as below

1. user control A fire a command which is to be handled by user control B.
2. main window recieves the command and fire a command to B
3. user control B handles the command.

My problem is how the main window can fire a command which can be handled in the VIEW MODEL of user control B?

Update:

SOLVED: One gloabl static RelayCommand for communication from the MainWindow to B and one Global RoutedCommand for communication from A to Main Window. Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not tagged `mvvm` (yet), but I am assuming it since you mention a ViewModel. So to begin with, let's agree that ViewModels handle commands, not controls. If a control want to respond to a command being executed, expose a suitable `CommandExecuted` event that the control (View) can attach a handler to.

There is however another unknown that I cannot blindly assume:

Do you take it for granted that user controls A and B exist at the same time? If yes, then a very simple and low-tech solution would be to maintain references to both ViewModels at some level (perhaps the ViewModel for the `Window` itself?) and "bubble" the command up to there, where the dispatch to ViewModel B will occur. If not (in which case control B might not exist), what is the desired behavior?

With the information you have given so far, I 'd suggest using the Event Aggregator/Mediator pattern implementation of your MVVM framework. For example, Prism has [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#EventAggregation); MVVM Light has [Messenger](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/#components); etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon, +1- I already looked into Event Aggregator, but cannot use it because I am doing just one module in a large application and the application is not using any framework. Yes, A and B exist at the same time, but maintaining references is some sort of coupling (though practically wont harm)which goes against what I am intending to do. I will try the view handling the event and call view model-still bad but no other easy way.

Comment: Problem solved, one gloabl static RelayCommand for communication from the MainWindow to B and one Global RoutedCommand for communication from A to Main Window.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you'd want to have a dependency property on B that the main window could bind to.  Your DP on B would then take the request and call it's view model.

The main window should not know anything about the inner workings of a Control.  It should only know about the exposed properties from the control.

Comment: Couldnt try this, but solved with different approach.One gloabl static RelayCommand for communication from the MainWindow to B and one Global RoutedCommand for communication from A to Main Window.