# Windows Phone - Bind Button of UserControl to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

i am struggling with binding a Button inside of a UserControl (which is placed inside of a ListBox.ItemTemplate) to my ViewModel.

Page A contains the following Listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbUpcomingBetgames" ItemsSource="{Binding UpcomingBetgames}" Background="{x:Null}">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,4"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <customControl:BetgameInfoControl x:Name="upcomingBetgameControl" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

My ViewModel contains a RelayCommand that i want to bind to in my CustomControl BetgameInfoControl:

```
public RelayCommand BetgameRegisterClicked
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

My CustomControl contains a Button:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Accept" Height="50" Command="{Binding Path=Parent.DataContext.BetgameRegisterClicked, ElementName=upcomingBetgameControl}" CommandParameter="{Binding Description}" />
```

The RelayCommand is never called. I tried different ways to bind the Command-Property in my Button but nothing worked.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339403/how-a-command-from-main-window-be-handled-in-a-usercontrol-view-model

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the datacontext of your button like this =>

```
DataContext={Binding ElementName=lbUpcomingBetgames,path=DataContext.BetgameRegisterClicked}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its still not working.

How would you set the Command-Attribute for the Button?

Comment: Oups sorry, i fail hard ^^ replace Datacontext={ by Command ={

Comment: I also tried that before and its not working either :(
Any other suggestions?